# How to avoid uploading all log files using .gitignore

Tags: github, gitignore

I am trying to avoid pushing appLog to git,
Here's my appLogs.
[image]
and I am using bellow list on .gitignore file,

```
appLog.log
appLog.log.*.gz
```

still github desktop is showing me the files in the list.
[image]

Can anyone pls help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern like `*.log*` in your `.gitignore` should work here.

Comment: No luck with this.

Comment: This is a less concrete example, but I just tested it and it works. Your examples in the question - `appLog.log` with `appLog.log.*.gz` also worked for me. I would suggest checking the placement on your `.gitignore` - is it in the git project's root? Or you could try a different github client, as it might be a display issue. What is shown when you try `git status` in your terminal?